# SSH agent forwarding from Windows to Linux VMs

Tags: linux, powershell, github, ssh, vagrant

I am trying to reuse the Github SSH key from Windows 10 laptop to vagrant VMs (that is where I run Ansible and connect to numerous EC2). I don't want to setup additional keys for every VM in GitHub since its a throwaway environment.

So...

On Github:

Pasted private key from my Windows laptop

[image]
On Windows 10:

- Connection to Github is established

[image]

- SSH agent is up

[image]

- Agent forwarding is enabled:

[image]

On Ubuntu 22.04 - managed by VirtualBox/Vagrant

1. Key added to authorized_keys
   [image]
2. No connection to Github:

   ```
    vagrant@ubuntu-jammy:~/.ssh$ ssh -T git@github.com -v
    OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.4] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-b9c2a189
    debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-b9c2a189
    debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    channel 1: chan_shutdown_read: shutdown() failed for fd 7 [i0 o0]: Not a socket
    debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
   ```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are not supposed to upload your private key to GitHub. It works the other way around. You create your key pair (public and private) and keep your private key secret. You put your public everywhere you want to login (e. g. on GitHub). On your Windows Laptop and also on your Vagrant machines, you use your private key to authenticate against GitHub.

Comment: From the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

Since the connection does work, what you have pasted on your [GitHub SSH setting page](https://github.com/settings/keys) is your *public* key, not your private one.

And the SSH agent is only needed if you have created the [private key as encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/129727).

> On Ubuntu 22.04 - managed by VirtualBox/Vagrant Key added to authorized_keys

That is only needed if you want to connect to the "VirtualBox/Vagrant".
Not when you want to connect *from* it.
From it, you only need in your Ubuntu `~/.ssh` the same public and private files than on your PC.

I would try the same setup with a passphrase-less private key, in order to check if the SSH agent is the issue (or if it does not work because of other factors, like network, firewall, ...).